# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. When the jobject is modified

Tags: c#, json, json.net

This was working fine earlier but not sure after I updated the newtonsoft version this started breaking .

This is the error that I am getting : Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

```
JObject jObjectFull = (JObject)dynObjFullJArray[index]; 
JArray     jArrayFull = (JArray)jObjectFull[packageName]; 
int fullCount = jObjectFull[packageName].Count();

                    if (packageName == "hello") 
                    {
                        if (ishello)
                        {
                            ishellochck= false;
                            jArrayFull.RemoveAll();
                        }

                        jArrayFull.Add(JObject.FromObject(dynObjItem));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (var item in jObjectFull[packageName])
                        {
                            int itemId = (int)item.SelectToken(selectedIdOrderNo.Split('|')[0]);
                            if (dynObjItemId == itemId)
                            {
                                //Edit
                                flag = true;
                                jArrayFull[i].Remove();
                                if (i == 0)
                                {
                                    if (fullCount > 1)
                                        jArrayFull[i].AddBeforeSelf(JObject.FromObject(dynObjItem));
                                    else
                                        jArrayFull.Add(JObject.FromObject(dynObjItem));
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (i == (fullCount - 1))
                                    {
                                        --i;
                                        jArrayFull[i].AddAfterSelf(JObject.FromObject(dynObjItem));
                                    }
                                    else
                                        jArrayFull[i].AddBeforeSelf(JObject.FromObject(dynObjItem));
                                }
                            }
                            i++;
                        }`
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what versions of Json.NET you were and are using, however it is *correct* that the exception is thrown, because you are modifying the collection through which you are iterating:

1. `jArrayFull` is defined to be `jObjectFull[packageName]`,
2. So when you do `jArrayFull[i].Remove()` you are actually doing `((JArray)jObjectFull[packageName]).RemoveAt(i)`, thereby modifying the collection.

[`JArray`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm) implements `IList<JToken>`, so perhaps you just want to do:

```
        JObject jObjectFull = (JObject)dynObjFullJArray[index];
        JArray jArrayFull = (JArray)jObjectFull[packageName];

        if (packageName == "hello")
        {
            if (ishello)
            {
                ishellochck = false;
                jArrayFull.RemoveAll();
            }

            jArrayFull.Add(JObject.FromObject(dynObjItem));
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0, fullCount = jArrayFull.Count; i < fullCount; i++)
            {
                int itemId = (int)jArrayFull[i].SelectToken(selectedIdOrderNo.Split('|')[0]);
                if (dynObjItemId == itemId)
                {
                    //Edit
                    flag = true;
                    jArrayFull[i] = JObject.FromObject(dynObjItem);
                    // Maybe break here?
                }
            }
        }
```